# How to write or append string in loop in a file in java?

Tags: java, file, collections, memory-leaks, filewriter

I'm having memory problem as working with very large dataset and getting memory leaks with char[] and Strings, don't know why! So I am thinking of writing some processed data in a file and not store in memory. So, I want to write texts from an arrayList in a file using a loop. First the program will check if the specific file already exist in the current working directory and if not then create a file with the specific name and start writing texts from the arrayList line by line using a loop; and if the file is already exist then open the file and append the 1st array value after the last line(in a new line) of the file and start writing other array values in a loop line by line.

Can any body suggest me how can I do this in Java? I'm not that good in Java so please provide some sample code if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: any effort of reasearch  or paste some bits of code you developed will be help ful toward providing you the solution or advice.

Comment: you might want to take a look at the 'StringBuilder' class for better performance with strings handling.

Comment: @E.Ar, performance can be different only if String is appended inside loop. Explicitly declaring StringBuilder before loop is a must to have good results, omitting this will result in creating StringBuilders objects on every iteration. But without loops concating strings is translated to StringBuilders by default (in byte code), from java 1.5, so there's not need to replace `+` with `StringBuilders.append(string)` in simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayList<String> StringarrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt", true); 
    for(String str: StringarrayList ) {
      writer.write(str + "\n");
    }
    writer.close();
```

Comment: in your example using loop makes no sense :)

Comment: if there is a mistake then you can correct it with a feedback and suggestion not just a smile we are not competing with each other we are just helping each other.

Comment: @dantuch: What's wrong with the [enhanced-for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)?

Comment: @Makoto not with for, wrong is parameter passed to write method. It should be single string, not whole list again and again. I hoped that @MMK would spot that after my comment. And going farer - it's good practice to not declare list as `ArrayList` but ruther as `List`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what parts of the process you are unsure of, so I'll start at the beginning.

The `Serializable` interface lets you write an object to a file. Any object that implemsents `Serializable` can be passed to an `ObjectOutputStream` and written to a file.

`ObjectOutputStream` accepts a `FileOutputStream` as argument, which can append to a file.

```
ObjectOutputstream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("filename", true));
outputStream.writeObject(anObject);
```

There is some exception handling to take care of, but these are the basics. Note that `anObject` should implement `Serializable`.

Reading the file is very similar, except it uses the Input version of the classes I mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

**// in main**

```
List<String> SarrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
.....
```

**fill it with content**

`enter content to SarrayList here`.....

**write to file**

```
appendToFile (SarrayList);
```

.....

```
public void appendToFile (List<String> SarrayList) {

      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      boolean myappend = true;
      try {
         bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myContent.txt", myappend));
         for(String line: SarrayList ) {
         bw.write(line);
         bw.newLine();
         }
         bw.flush();
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
      } finally { 
        if (bw != null) try {
        bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe2) {
        // ignore it  or write notice
        }
      }

   }
```